# Django - ModuleNotFoundError (basic app to print Hello in browser)

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django so take me easy. I'm just following some youtube tutorials and try to make a simple app to print Hello on the browser with django. And I keep getting this error in the urls.py file
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
I get this error in urls.py file of my project which is bellow:

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I also made an app called app

**app\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name = 'home'),
]
```

**app\views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello!')
```

I read I think all threads on this topic and nothing helped so far and I can't realise where's my mistake or what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your settings.py, add `'app.apps.AppConfig',` in INSTALLED APP. You have to register the newly made apps to settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app.apps.AppConfig',    // Added the name of app 
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
]
```

*Note:- Everytime you add an app, register it in settings.py

Comment: I've done that. I run the settings file with no error. But still doesn't solve the issue

Comment: just load the new app at the bottom of default apps. so that the default apps which are handling the core functionality of django gets loaded first and then the data of your app. It also prevents mysterious bugs :)

Comment: upload your models.py file here

Comment: I haven't added any code in models.py. There they way django makes them when you create a project.